# MVC 3 website: How to store & manage uploaded files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC and pretty new to web sites development. I have a dilemma how to manage uploaded images.

I have a data layer that uses entity framework in order to store data. 
In my controller constructor I give the IItemRepository and an IFileRepository implementations.

```
 public ItemsController(IItemManager itemRepository, IFilesRepository fileRepository)
```

Mow I store the files in db (filename, mime type, relative server path) and the actual file is stored on the disk. In the controller I do the sync between the database and the folder. Is that the right approach? It seems to me that it is not. I am thinking of moving the IFileRepository into the IItemManager implementation.

Another problem is that for every controller that require files I have to implement the same sync between db and folder structure.

What do you think of storing files in the db?

How did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See this [SO post about saving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535627/where-is-the-best-place-to-save-images-from-users-upload). The same cases are applicable in case of other files too.

Answer (score 0):

> In the controller I do the sync between the database and the folder. 
>   Is that the right approach?

No.

I would start by moving most logic (including this synch) to a model so that (1) your controller does not do a whole lot and (2) you can share this logic with other controllers.