# How to save an image path into a file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I want to save an image into a file and also retrieve that image as my application requirement.

I have a project in ASP.NET MVC. I am using G-light Box for better view of the image but I want to implement dynamic image functionality like,

How can I save an image in the Image folder and also retrieve from image from this image file?

Please check the following code.

```
   if (submit == "submit")
        {
            string[] Names = Imagefile.FileName.Split('.');
            String NewfileName = 2 + "." + Names[1];
            string RootFolder =Server.MapPath("~//Image//");
           List<cCreateFolder> collCreateFolder = new List<cCreateFolder>();
            collCreateFolder.Add(new cCreateFolder(Denver.DenLibrary.cUtil.ToString(1)));
            cCreateFolder createFolder = new cCreateFolder();
            string fullPath = createFolder.getFolderPath(collCreateFolder, RootFolder);
            Request.Files[0].SaveAs(fullPath + NewfileName);
            Homemodel.FileExtn = NewfileName;
```

}

```html
<img src="~/Image/9739801B-930A-4AD8-B8D0-50B1EDA771F7-1.jpg" />
```

Comment: In above code, i`m able to save image but i am not getting in view side this image after save in image-folder.

Comment: Related advice on where/how to store files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4535684/224370

Comment: my dear friend, i need suggestion what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Your C# code shows `NewfileName` starting with `2.`, but your output doesn't - surely that tells you something?

Comment: i`m not getting your point. do you have any specific idea.

Comment: 1) Look on disk to see if the file is where you expect it to be; 
2) Simplify the problem - we have no idea what `cCreateFolder` does.
3) Use a debugger to step through your saving code to see what happens

Comment: ok i got it. but my problem is i am not getting file in html even-if i am retrieving it from same directory where i saved the file.