# Upload image to folder MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload the image in my project Releases folder. But it is not uploading in the desired place. Even though it shows the "file uploaded successfully" message.

> [image]

Controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadImages(HttpPostedFileBase photo_url)
{         
    if (photo_url != null)
    try
    { 
        photo_url.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Releases"), 
        photo_url.FileName));
        ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
    }
    return View(); 
}
```

Comment: _"it is not uploading in the desired place"_ - so where _is_ it uploading to?

Comment: why don't you try to use the debugger and find out the combined path. If it uploads to file successfully, the path has to be there for you to inspect.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535684/224370

Comment: Also please do not add code as images. Paste your `View` in the same way you did with your controller ?!

Comment: If you are running in debug mode it might put it in the folder your project is in. Is this while building or deployed to a server