# Can upload image using ASP.NET WEB API but not when deployed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I am using ASP.NET WEB API to upload image to server. But when i upload the source code of my web api to gearhost.com and make a post request. I am unable to post the image. This is my web api controller code:

```
[Route("upload")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Upload()
{
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    var root = ctx.Server.MapPath("/uploads/");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try
    {
        await Request.Content
                .ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
        {
            var name = file.Headers
                           .ContentDisposition
                           .FileName;

            // remove double quotes from string.
            name = name.Trim('"');

            var localFileName = file.LocalFileName;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(root, "files", name);

            // File.Move(localFileName, filePath);
            // SaveFilePathSQLServerADO(localFileName, filePath);
            // SaveFileBinarySQLServerADO(localFileName, name);

            // SaveFilePathSQLServerEF(localFileName, filePath);
            SaveFileBinarySQLServerEF(localFileName, name, filePath);

            if (File.Exists(localFileName))
                File.Delete(localFileName);
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        return "Error";
    }

    return "File uploaded successfully!";
}

public void SaveFileBinarySQLServerEF(string localFile, string fileName, string filePath)
{
    // 1) Get file binary
    byte[] fileBytes;

    using (var fs = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fileBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    }

    // 2) Create a Files object
    var file = new tblimage()
                   {
                       Data = fileBytes,
                       Names = fileName,
                       ContentType = filePath
                   };

    // 3) Add and save it in database
    using (var ctx = new coachEntities())
    {
        ctx.tblimages.Add(file);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here is the successful call from localhost:

[Image posted through localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCEVJ.png)

However when deployed the same code and make request through postman then I get this error:

[Image posted through live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6TLZ.png)

Comment: Not an answer but please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535684/224370
It would be better to place the images in the temporary folder using a Guid-based name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, "uploads" doesn't have write permission
Check the permission in your uploads folder.
Go to properties-- security
Give the read write permission.

Comment: Can you give me details on how to give full access to a specific folder?

Comment: I am considering, it is a windows server. Go to your server.right click on "uploads" folder. Go to properties then security then edit then select IIS group name then check allow write then apply. Now check it is working or not

Comment: How unable to upload, try again is coming? Where u r returning from?

Comment: Though it is not good idea to return the exception details in live code. As you are not maintaining log. For testing, Please return the exception details. Also, how are you getting the response like "unable to upload, try again" because it is not there in your code

Comment: Somnath Ghosh actually i had written a bit different message exception for live code actually this is the live code but rest is pretty much same. https://github.com/Zeeshan-H/CoachAcademy. Under controller folder goto userscontroller. Although the controller code i shared earlier is also the same, just exception message differs.

Comment: Please tell me what exception you are getting?

Comment: I am getting "unable to upload try again".

Comment: Can you give me your Skype id? i can share screen with you to let you solve this issue efficiently.

Comment: Install anydesk. Give me your anydesk id

Comment: This is my ID: 408 445 047

Comment: Ok. Trying to connect. Accept it

Comment: Brother you are not replying to my messages at anydesk

Comment: I want to make sure that you don't do anything wrong with my system.

Comment: Sorry,i didn't see. I will connect now. Please keep notepad open

Comment: I dont think anydesk is safe. Please for my security, come onto skype.

Comment: We can talk to each other formally.

Comment: somnath ghosh would like to chat with you on Skype. It’s free!

https://join.skype.com/invite/n8QI49nJfGyH

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not good idea to return the exception details in live code. As you are not maintaining log. For testing, Please return the exception details. Also, how are you getting the response like "unable to upload, try again" because it is not there in your code